# Devise "Confirm account instructions email" takes me to "Reset Password"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, confirmation-email

Once you `sign_up`, you get a confirmation email.

Do not confirm. Instead go to the app and click on `didn't receive confirmation instructions` and enter the same email id.

You will get a `reset password instructions` email instead of `confirmation email`.

Is this a `devise` bug, has anyone else encountered this problem ?

**code for confirmation email**

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <div class="input">
      <%= f.email_field :email, :class => 'xlarge' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions"> 
    <%= button_tag "Resend confirmation instructions", :class => 'btn primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: what version of devise are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a Devise bug. I created a [sample application](https://github.com/rodrigoflores/devise-confirmable-as-reset-password/) that tries to reproduce this, but I couldn't find this behaviour ([I have also uploaded the log](https://github.com/rodrigoflores/devise-confirmable-as-reset-password/blob/master/log/development.log)).

**EDIT (added when you added the pasted code):**

You're using `:url => password_path(resource_name)` instead of `:url => confirmation_path(resource_name)`. Doing this, you send a reset password request to passwordsController instead of a resend confirmation.